# accessing elements of an object returned by confint()

Tags: r

Example code

```
data(anorexia, package = "MASS")
anorex.1 <- glm(Postwt ~ Prewt + Treat + offset(Prewt),
            family = gaussian, data = anorexia)
confint(anorex.1)
```

This produces

```
                 2.5 %     97.5 %
(Intercept) 23.5253133 76.0169047
Prewt       -0.8814505 -0.2496272
TreatCont   -7.8082428 -0.3858882
TreatFT      0.3818011  8.7443242
```

I would now like to access these confidence intervals, for example, creating a 4 variables.  What are the preferred ways to do this ? I know I can use

```
Intercept <- c(confint(anorex.1)[1],confint(anorex.1)[5])
Prewt <- c(confint(anorex.1)[2],confint(anorex.1)[6])
```

etc... but this seems unwieldy and inelegant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assign the resultant matrix to a name and then extract rows by name:

```
resCI <- confint(anorex.1)
IntCI <- resCI[ "(Intercept)", ]
PrewtCI <- resCI[ "Prewt", ]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply wrap in `data.frame()` if that's the sort of output you would like?

```
data.frame(confint(anorex.1))
                X2.5..    X97.5..
(Intercept) 23.5253133 76.0169047
Prewt       -0.8814505 -0.2496272
TreatCont   -7.8082428 -0.3858882
TreatFT      0.3818011  8.7443242
```

And the broom package makes things a lot easier to get everything at once.

```
require(broom)
tidy(anorex.1, conf.int=TRUE)
         term   estimate  std.error statistic      p.value   conf.low  conf.high
1 (Intercept) 49.7711090 13.3909581  3.716770 0.0004101067 23.5253133 76.0169047
2       Prewt -0.5655388  0.1611824 -3.508689 0.0008034250 -0.8814505 -0.2496272
3   TreatCont -4.0970655  1.8934926 -2.163761 0.0339993147 -7.8082428 -0.3858882
4     TreatFT  4.5630627  2.1333359  2.138933 0.0360350847  0.3818011  8.7443242
```